# Getting stuck at “sudo apt-get upgrade” on Parrot OS

Tags: linux, apt, parrot-os

I have Parrot OS headless running on a Raspberry Pi. I started the upgrade but it now has stopped at:

```
Installing new version of config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove
```

The output before was:

```
Setting up apt (1.8.1+parrot1)
```

I have only installed `wpa_supplicant` and I can get into the system with SSH.

So what can I do now? Kill the `apt` process? Delete this autoremove config file. Any idea?

It’s been this way for about 2 hours since starting the upgrade and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> isn’t working either.

EDIT: Later, after I had rebooted `apt` said I should use a `dpkg` command because I killed the last `apt` and `dpkg` process.

Now I have retried `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it said that one package is damaged or something. I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and now its stuck at

```
Setting up apt (1.8.1+parrot1)
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parrot is a rolling release distro. So apt upgrade also tries to upgrade 'core' packages and partial upgrade can break things. You should use apt full-upgrade or apt-get dist-upgrade. Otherwise see the dpkg log after running fix broken to find what went wrong..

Answer (score 0):

This trouble happens for several reasons, as any Linux distribution the most probably is that the repository is not updated, so what is recomended is:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/* 

sudo apt-get update
```

If this is not working is better to change the download repositories

Editing source.list

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/source.list
```

https://www.parrotsec.org/docs/mirror-list/

Usually this works for all Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I used `sudo parrot-upgrade` instead of using apt, as the documentation specifies not to use `apt upgrade` for ParrotOS.